# Node.js absolute path and relative path results in 2 separate references or are they the same?

Tags: node.js

I am curious to know how Nodejs would treat the following imports:

`import * as redis from 'app/api/redis/index';
   require('../../../../app/api/redis/index');`

If both requires lead to the same directory, would node consider them the same or two separate modules?

I am aware that Nodejs will consider /app/api/redis/Index to be a different module vs. /app/api/redis/index because nodes imports/require is case sensitive but I am not sure what will happen in the former case.

Comment: Are you asking if the imported objects be considered `===` to each other?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering if i modify a property on one, will the modification be reflected on the other.  This is a scenario for unit testing and mocking, I am having a unit test fail intermittently even though a service is being mocked.